# Where does an electron get energy from after passing a single slit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

An electron with a very low velocity $v_1$ after passing a narrow slit can get a very high velocity $v_2$ because of Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. We place a passive detector to observe it, so the detector can not supply impulse in any way. So logically, the electron took energy from somewhere?

Comment: If you know its velocity is $v_1$, then you don't know if it has passed the narrow slit and vice versa.

Comment: Its only the velocity parallel to the slit  witch  may be affected, not the speed and for that the energy .

Comment: It looks like you had mixed some classical into your quantum. How do you know these velocities without first measuring the momentum?

Comment: @BioPhysicist I dont mix anything. I have a flux of electrons which velocity is known  to some extent. I dont insist that it is precise. Some voltage may accelerate them. So QM model them as a plane wave. Some of them pass classically or not? Crucial is that v1 is low. Classically or nor they had v1 low before the slit.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I dont insist I know v1 exactly but to some extent and I know it is low. If throw a ball can you not control the speed? And if you know you throw weakly then your ball can not pass through a door?

Answer (score 0):

Its only the velocity parallel to the slit  witch  may be affected, not the speed and for that the energy .So you can explain , that it arrives not in the middle but in the first maximum  of the interference pattern .

Comment: Ok the speed parallel to the slit is 0 while they fall perpendicular to it. After the slit v (parallel) rises  and v (perpendicular) stays v1. Then obviously v total rises and Energy too.

Comment: Why do you suppose "v (perpendicular) stays v1. " ?

Comment: Because  v(perp)=v1 has not to obey HUP. And you also say it: "only velocity parallel to the slits may be affected". You tell why?

Comment: Only the velocity parallel to the slit is involved with   Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle because only the location in this direction is know. The energy is not changed by the slit so the speed - a far as known - is conserved

Comment: So the parallel velocity is almost 0 or near 0. After the slit it changes p/m=h/dx. If dx is small p is much above 0. v perpendicular does not change as you say. So v=v(perp)+v(paral) change and hence Energy is also changed. Is there something wrong?

Comment: I can have very slow electrons also falling one by one on the slit - so v(perp) is around 0. So E is low. After passing the slit v (parallel) increses and v(per) = 0. The new v is greater than initial! So E increses, total v too. How than E is not changed by the slit. Is it changed or not?

Comment: the slit does not change the energy, did you calculate  the wavelength of your slow e? and the slit it should go through

Comment: As p increases there is no way E not to increase. However big the WL of the electron it has some chance to pass tru the slit.

Comment: Maybe I post a new question: Can an electron have greater v and E after leaving a slit?